# Javascript searching for keywords in the HTML, surrounding them with em tags

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to search through HTML and surround keywords with an `<em>` tag. I would like to search through a list of words that show up regularly on a series of pages.

ex. : *search for [foo, bar]*

html before:

```
....
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>consectetur FOO adipiscing elit</li>
<li>Ut at convallis nisl BAR</li>
....
```

html after:

```
....
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>consectetur <em>FOO</em> adipiscing elit</li>
<li>Ut at convallis nisl <em>BAR</em></li>
....
```

The text I'm searching will be static once it has loaded, it will always be in a list tag if that helps, and the keywords can be defined within the javascript, so I don't think the answer should be too hard to find. I've found a couple similar topics in here, but nothing quite like what I'm trying for and usually too complicated to alter with my limited skills.

The goal is to have the script added to a series of pages to avoid hand coding all of the emphasis tags, and then styling the tags with CSS.

Any help or links to similar queries would be appreciated!

Comment: `replace(/(foo|bar)/gi, function() { '<em>$1</em>' })`

Comment: [Here](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) is a jQuery plugin that does more-or-less what you want. I don't mean to push jQuery on you; instead I offer it as some source code to look at.

Comment: @qwertymk What if the OP has a sentence like "Jack Thompson got disbarred."?

Comment: This should probably be done server-side. Its better to translate the page just once instead of forcing it to be rerendered everytime (and this is not counting usability issues like disabled JS or the page changing after being loaded)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I had looked at some jQuery highlight plugins but they were a bit overkill and I wasn't fluent enough in javascript to slim down the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for an implementation of the request:

```
// Keys
var keys = ["foo", "bar"];

// Create regular expression for a global and dynamic search and replace
var pattern = [];
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    // Create RegExp. This section is needed to deal with special chars
    pattern.push(keys[i].replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, "\\$1"));
}
pattern = "\\b(" + pattern.join("|") + ")\\b";
pattern = new RegExp(pattern, "g"); //Replace g by gi for case-insensitivity

var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i=0, l=li.length; i<l; i++) {
    li[i].innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML.replace(pattern, "<em>$1</em>");
}
```

A regular expression is used, so that the keys don't interfere with each other. If a normal search and replace, without a RegExp, is used, the following keys will interfere with each other: `"cowsayMoo" "cowsay"`. Without a RegExp, the result will be: `<em><em>cowsay</em>Moo</em>`. However, since weŕe using a RegExp, this problem is solved.

Link:

- [MDN: Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: That did it, thanks! (I think there is an extra ; after the RegExp, I took it out and it worked flawlessly). Thanks for the g->gi tip too, I would have run into this down the way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var emKeywords = function(text, kws) {
  var regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + kws.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");
  return text.replace(regex, function(m) {
    return "<em>" + m + "</em>";
  });
};

var htmlAfter = emKeywords(htmlBefore, ['foo', 'bar']);
htmlAfter; // => "...<em>FOO</em>...<em>BAR</em>..."
```

Note that the second argument must be a list of strings.  This function also puts word boundaries around each word, ensuring that it would not mangle things like "Jack Thompson got dis*bar*red".